# mysql repeated data in rows vs join performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with information that is imported from different files. Some columns of this information are the same for all files. (e.g. the unique person by id peter@example.com, will have the same name and city in all files.)
However some other information is not always the same (e.g. amount)

```
id, file_id, amount, email, name, city, ...
1, 1, 30, peter@example.com, peter, paris
2, 1, 50, mary@example.com, mary, berlin
3, 2, 12, peter@example.com, peter, paris
...
```

I currently consider to put the duplicate information in a separate table:

```
data
id, file_id, amount, email_data_id
1, 1, 30, 1
2, 1, 50, 2
3, 2, 12, 1


email_data
id, email, name, city
1, peter@example.com, peter, paris
2, mary@example.com, mary, berlin
```

I am concerned that this may impact query performance since it will need to use a join. Does the database handle this well or is it better to stick with the duplicates in order to improve query times?

Comment: The two tables is generally the better approach (there are exceptions).  Performance may *improve* using a `join`, because the overall volume of data will be smaller.

Comment: be sure to index correctly or joins will be horrible slow

Answer (score 0):

JOIN's aren't always bad, in fact, as Gordon stated in his comment, in specific circumstances using a join will even be faster since you will be needing less data to store everything in.

Generally, unless you're processing HUGE amounts of data, the query executing speed for non-complex queries will not be your bottleneck, but things like AJAX response time (in a webserver environment) will be.

I would go with the 2 tables approach, as it also reduces the possibility to create insert delete and update anomalies and your single table approach violates the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself).

There are exceptions to this, but they're very specific and your case doesn't appear to be one.